# Invalid change type for NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate calls

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

NSFetchedResultControllerDelegate call didChangeObject gets passed invalid change type. The value is 0, valid values are 1 to 4 for Insert, Delete, Move, and Update respectively.

I do get all the expected delegate calls with the correct parameters. So, the app works fine. For every 3 to 5 calls, I get one with change type 0 and I have to add logic to ignore it and I would like not have to.

I am using Xcode 7 beta 4, swift 2. Has anyone run into the same and figured it out the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into the same using Xcode 7 beta 5, running the app on a device with iOS 8.4.
This seems to be a bug which only happens if you run the app on iOS 8 - it makes extra calls to the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate method with change type 0 (rawValue). On iOS 9 it should be ok.

This issue has also been [mentioned](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12184) on Apple Developer forums.

**Edit:** Still present in GM seed.

**Edit2 / another temporary fix:** If you have an .Insert case before .Update in your controller:didChangeObject, try moving .Update up so that it's the first case (suggested [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4999#53526)).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I've summed up the information I could find about this issue (which I also ran into), the link was just the description from another user on Apple Developer forums. Nevertheless, I've edited the answer to be more clear.